# Process 'command' C: \ Program Files \ Java \ jdk1.8.0_31 \ bin \ java.exe '' finished with a non -zero exit value 2

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

When I try to build, I experience errors like this:

> Error: Execution failed for task ': app: dexRelease'.
>   Com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command' C: \ Program Files \ Java \ jdk1.8.0_31 \ bin \ java.exe '' finished with a non -zero exit value 2

Comment: I am also currently experiencing this failure... from my research it has something to do with overlapping dependencies but unfortunately I have no idea how to resolve project dependencies within android studio so that I can exclude the correct dependenies. Although your issue is different come to think of it you aren't suppose to use java8 with android yet, download java 7 jdk

Comment: then I tried to use the JDK 1.7 but when I try to still tetep with the same problem ... the error looks like this longcat

Error: Execution failed for the task ': app: dexDebug'.
> Com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command' C: \ Program Files \ Java \ jdk1.7.0_79 \ bin \ java.exe '' finished with a non -zero exit value 2

I am confused with this problem ?? 1 week already encountered the same problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30320057/android-project-process-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2