# :app:dexDebug ExecException finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Could anyone help me out with the following error. When i clean the project, it doesn't show any error but every time i try to run i get this message.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

The application was running with no errors but as my system crashed and restarted android studio i had few updates for Android API 22. After the update the application keep giving me this error message. I downloaded JDK 8 and tried to run but didn't work. Later i downgraded to JDK 7 after this stack post but still has not fixed it.
[Is it possible to use Java 8 for Android development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318109/is-it-possible-to-use-java-8-for-android-development)

I have looked through numerous similar question but none works for me. Some similar issues found on stack were

[why java.exe exit with value 1 in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28957412/why-java-exe-exit-with-value-1-in-android-studio/29236320#)

[Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. > comcommand finished with non-zero exit value 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29747363/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug-comcommand-finished-with-non)

[Java finished with non-zero exit value 2 - Android Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756188/java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-android-gradle)

[java.exe finished with non-zero exit value 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29998783/java-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-after-upgrading-play-service)

[Process 'command' C: \ Program Files \ Java \ jdk1.8.0_31 \ bin \ java.exe '' finished with a non -zero exit value 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837352/process-command-c-program-files-java-jdk1-8-0-31-bin-java-exe-fi)

I have looked through dependencies in gradle built to see if there were any conflict but found none.

I even tried to copy the code into a new project and run it but still no success. Anyone who has faced the same issue and solved it please help me out.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

After days of trying out finally could fix the issue. The problem with one of my .jar files. I had to remove each jar and check one by one until i found it. I removed the .jar file and cleaned my project and ran successfully. If any one should face similar issue check your jar file one by one.

Comment: It is issue of duplicate lib??

Comment: you don't even need to try one by one !! if you read carefully the log you can find where the problem come from

Comment: Great Job, The solution is : delete all jars, and add 1 to 1 and works :)

Comment: @BhaveshHirpara Yea, duplicate libs in my case. Had Parse lib .jar and declared in gradle build.

Answer (score 30):

I had the same error

> app:dexDebug ExecException finished with non-zero exit value 2

i solve it by adding this line of code

```
defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
}
```

The reason is that i was using too many libraries

Hope this post will help anyone

Comment: this code go in your gradle build file, for more information see : http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem when I compiled google play services to my dependencies.

My mistake was I was compiling the enitre package like this

**compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'**

Instead when I tried the selective compile, it worked.In my case I was using for google sign in,so it had just had to be

**compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'.**

More details are in the documentaion. https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split

Hope this will be of a little help to someone someday :)

Comment: Worked for me, Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's late.
But that's what actually worked for me.

```
1. Build > Clean Project
2. Close gradle daemon processes (ps -e| grep gradle  //this will list gradle processes)
3. File > Invalidate caches & Restart
```

I hope this will work for everyone.

Answer (score 3):

For me the solution was to remove an unnecessary/duplicate dependency entries. This is a similar solution others offered here that makes sense, but not exactly the same solution as those offered by others.

Since I was already including *.jar files in the list of files to be compiled, there was no need for additional entries in the dependencies list.

Before:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
}
```

After:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
```

}

Answer (score 3):

For future readers.  If you're using your own AARs and upgraded one that has a shared dependency, you can also just try cleaning the project.  In Android Studio "Build" -> "Clean Project".

This solved the issue for me, so I'd recommend giving it a quick try before you start digging for dependencies.

Comment: This happens more if the AARs are part of source control, and pushed by other developers.  (switch to a local maven server)

Answer (score 2):

Remove
 `compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'`

add this line`compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['Parse-*.jar'])`

Finally, it will look like this

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['Parse-*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, just i did Biuld--> Rebiuld project and it works again ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was using the robolectric dependency in my android project. I removed all robolectric dependencies in gradle and deleted all my robolectric tests, then I built the app and finally I could run the android project. Hope this can work for us.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when trying to add the [SignalR Java client](https://github.com/SignalR/java-client) library to my project's dependencies. I first changed the target JDK of my app from 1.8.0_XX to 1.7.0_XX, but it didn't work. Then I changed the SignalR project to target 1.7.0_XX as well, rebuilt and added it to my project's libs folder instead of the first build (which was in 1.8.0_XX), and that miraculously worked.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that I was using different versions of "Google Play services sub API's"

**Before:**
[Click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcMK3.png)

**After:**
[Click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALWyp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are 2 classes with same name. Each class name should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

maybe for this issue you got means you added same liberay file in more than one time