# Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored

Tags: java, android, dependencies

When I try adding any of the the .jar files that are in my **libs2** folder to my **libs** folder 
[image]

I get the following error:

```
    Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
    Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
             In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
    Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
             In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
    :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
   .....
    :app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileDebugSources
    :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
    > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

I know for a fact that the files in **libs2** cause the error since I would add them one by one and see which ones would cause a problem or not, based on this persons [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30001051/appdexdebug-execexception-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2).

I am following a [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-youtube-client-on-android--cms-22858) which requires all of those .jar files, so I do not understand why I am getting those errors since they are necessary.

Answer (score 3):

with `Gradle` no need to downgrade or to find another jar - since one can filter per group/module:

```
compile ('com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.21.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In 5.0 and above (api 23+) http client is depricated adn doesnt even exists downgrade your maxsdk or use url connection 
in your case you should find the latest jar files which are compatible with api23+

Comment: Ok Im gonna try that and see how it goes.