# what are the necessary gradle files for setting up appium in android studio

Tags: android, appium

I am learning `Appium`. Please help me in setting up this with in android studio.
I referred some of the document but fail to understand it properly. so please help me out.

**Edit**   after adding following dependencies

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'io.appium:java-client:3.3.0'
compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.1'
compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.21.0'
compile 'com.testdroid:testdroid-api:2.9'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.21.0'
```

and if i run my application it shows following error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
```

> 

```
'com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1'
```

Comment: http://bitbar.com/appium-tip-20-executing-appium-tests-with-gradle/

Comment: I have referred this blog after adding dependencies and run my android application it showing error

Comment: I will post log cat

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `multiDexEnabled true` to your app **build.gradle** file.

```
 defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

In case it happens frequently or first step didn't help `multiDexEnabled` might help. For those who love to dig deeper here is couple similar issues (with more answers):

[:app:dexDebug ExecException finished with non-zero exit value 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30001051/2146871)

[Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28917696/2146871)