# generating Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>     com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin\java.exe'' finished with
>   non-zero exit value 1

here is my gradle.build file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'maven'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.dumainfotech.pratibimb"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}

   dexOptions {
   javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
   preDexLibraries = false
}



}


dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
   }
```

because i already did but it's not working in my case
any help appreciate.
thank you !

Comment: post your build.gradle

Comment: look again.. i edit my query and add my gradle file content.

Comment: remove multidex dependency and set multidex to false

Comment: @DharmeshDhameliya call `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'` Then `Clean-Rebuild-Sync` .Let me inform .

Comment: It's not working @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: @DharmeshDhameliya comment `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'`

Comment: i tried everything relevant to dex, but nothing is working

Comment: see my answer here for your solution [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30410140/android-studio-java-exe-is-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2/34790268#34790268)

Comment: we have the same error, but this happens when i migrated my code to android studio gradle alpha5